# Column Select by default in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to know if there is a way to enable the "Column Select" mode by default in Sublime, i mean, that if i select text without pressing option, just selecting text with the mouse, it selects in column mode instead of "normal" mode (and to select in normal mode when holding option)

If there is a simple way of enabling it, it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Column Selection

For reference, [here is the official documentation on the default mouse bindings for column selection](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/column_selection.html).

## Mouse Bindings

As [this forum post highlights](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&p=44810), mouse binding preferences are not accessible through the menu, but can be overridden.  The default bindings are set in the `Default` package that ships with Sublime Text, and are platform specific: `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`, `Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap` and `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap`.

## Swap behavior

To swap the behavior so that a simple drag select with the mouse operates in column mode, you will need to edit the relevant file, which is in JSON format. The recommended way is to extract it (see below) to your `Packages/User` folder - i.e. the same place where your User Preferences are stored - and edit it there.  This will then override what is in the Default package.  You can get to this folder from the Sublime Text Preferences menu -> Browse Packages, and going to the `User` subdirectory.

### Accessing the files in the Default package

The easiest way to get to these `.sublime-mousemap` files in the Default package is to install [the PackageResourceViewer plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer), and from the Command Palette, use `PackageResourceViewer: Extract Resource` and navigate to `Default` and the file you want.

### Mouse Bindings - `drag_select` command

The `"press_command"` is `"drag_select"`, and whether or not it operates in column mode depends on whether `"press_args"` contains a `"by"` key with a value of `"columns"`.

In the `.sublime-mousemap` files, the "normal" mode bindings are under the comment `// Basic drag select`, and the "column select" mode bindings are under the comment that ends with `Column select`.

Comment: This! I did a little research about that file and found more info, it's the same syntax as the classic keybind file. Made a new bind with the "press_args": {"by": "columns"} flag and worked perfect, thanks a lot bro!